# How can I catch callback url in Evernote Python API through default interface?

Tags: python, api, callback, evernote

I've looked lots of place but I can't find answer how can I implement it. My program is little sync app using Python Evernote API and *.txt file. I've used to auth for developer token and I need to auth for any user who uses to Evernote. I'm using interface as Tkinter and I need to g.e. "Log in with Evernote" button to going requests to Evernote and catching the callback url and including my program to 
 `auth_token = "*****"
    client = EvernoteClient(token=auth_token, sandbox=True)`

Comment: What is exactly the question?

Comment: The question is how can I implement the code taking any user who uses Evernote to authentication app and cathing auth_token using callback url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback URL is for applications that utilize OAuth to obtain an access token to act on behalf of another user.  OAuth is a separate authentication system from developer tokens which are for quickly accessing the API to test an application or to develop an application that only accesses your account; you cannot use developer tokens to access others accounts (its a violation of the API policy).

To access other's Evernote accounts, you need to use OAuth.  First you must get a consumer key and consumer secret.  The consumer key uniquely identifies your application and your consumer secret should never be shared but is used by your application to validate your use of your consumer key.  You can get one here: https://dev.evernote.com/#apikey

For an example of how to use your consumer key and consumer secret to create an application that access the user's Evernote account see this small (~240 lines) example I created using the Python web framework Flask: https://github.com/matthewayne/evernote-giphy/blob/master/server.py

To learn how Evernote's OAuth work see Evernote authentication page: https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/authentication.php